# OCI APM domain with Istio zipkin not pushing tracing details

Tags: istio, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, zipkin, istio-sidecar

i am following this document to set up the distributed tracing : https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Tasks/contengistio-intro-topic.htm#exploring_istio_observability

My Cluster is on GKE GCP for testing purposes, installed istio top of it and followed document and setup services.

Services are up and running with Prometheus, Grafana, Jeger & Zipkin.

It's failing from step : Performing Distributed Tracing with OCI Application Performance Monitoring.

Tried udpating configmap for sidecar injector so that i can push tracing details to zipkin domain.

Configured Zipkin domain and using `public-span` use of now in **configmap**.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: istio-custom-bootstrap-config
  namespace: default
data:
  custom_bootstrap.json: |
    {
        "tracing": {
            "http": {
                "name": "envoy.tracers.zipkin",
                "typed_config": {
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.trace.v3.ZipkinConfig",
                    "collector_cluster": "aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com", // [Replace this with data upload endpoint of your apm domain]
                    "collector_endpoint": "/20200101/observations/private-span?dataFormat=zipkin&dataFormatVersion=2&dataKey=2C6YOLQSUZ5Q7IGN", // [Replace with the private datakey of your apm domain. You can also use public datakey but change the observation type to public-span]
                    "collectorEndpointVersion": "HTTP_JSON",
                    "trace_id_128bit": true,
                    "shared_span_context": false
                }
            }
        },
        "static_resources": {
            "clusters": [{
                "name": "aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com", // [Replace this with data upload endpoint of your apm domain:443]
                "type": "STRICT_DNS",
                "lb_policy": "ROUND_ROBIN",
                "load_assignment": {
                    "cluster_name": "aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com", // [Replace this with data upload endpoint of your apm domain]
                    "endpoints": [{
                        "lb_endpoints": [{
                            "endpoint": {
                                "address": {
                                    "socket_address": {
                                        "address": "aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com", // [Replace this with data upload endpoint of your apm domain]
                                        "port_value": 443
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }]
                },
                "transport_socket": {
                    "name": "envoy.transport_sockets.tls",
                    "typed_config": {
                        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext",
                        "sni": "aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com" // [Replace this with data upload endpoint of your apm domain]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```

above configmap not working as expected, the sidecar is crashing due to missing key `connection_timeout` although after adding in configmap sidecar not showing error.

There is no error found in `Zipkin` or `Istiod` containers, not sure how to debug further.

Error log :

```
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146580Z     info    FLAG: --concurrency="2"
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146632Z     info    FLAG: --domain="default.svc.cluster.local"
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146642Z     info    FLAG: --help="false"
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146648Z     info    FLAG: --log_as_json="false"
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146672Z     info    FLAG: --log_caller=""
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146678Z     info    FLAG: --log_output_level="default:info"
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146682Z     info    FLAG: --log_rotate=""
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146687Z     info    FLAG: --log_rotate_max_age="30"
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146693Z     info    FLAG: --log_rotate_max_backups="1000"
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146699Z     info    FLAG: --log_rotate_max_size="104857600"
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146704Z     info    FLAG: --log_stacktrace_level="default:none"
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146715Z     info    FLAG: --log_target="[stdout]"
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146725Z     info    FLAG: --meshConfig="./etc/istio/config/mesh"
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146730Z     info    FLAG: --outlierLogPath=""
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146736Z     info    FLAG: --proxyComponentLogLevel="misc:error"
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146741Z     info    FLAG: --proxyLogLevel="warning"
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146747Z     info    FLAG: --serviceCluster="reviews.default"
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146753Z     info    FLAG: --stsPort="0"
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146760Z     info    FLAG: --templateFile=""
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146767Z     info    FLAG: --tokenManagerPlugin="GoogleTokenExchange"
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146784Z     info    Version 1.8.0-c87a4c874df27e37a3e6c25fa3d1ef6279685d23-Clean
2022-03-30T05:59:33.146991Z     info    Obtained private IP [10.4.1.6]
2022-03-30T05:59:33.147107Z     info    Apply proxy config from env {"tracing":{"zipkin":{"address":"caadc76wvdp7edddddddccclii.apm-agt.ap-mumbai-1.oci.oraclecloud.com:443"}},"proxyMetadata":{"DNS_AGENT":""}}

2022-03-30T05:59:33.148650Z     info    Effective config: binaryPath: /usr/local/bin/envoy
concurrency: 2
configPath: ./etc/istio/proxy
controlPlaneAuthPolicy: MUTUAL_TLS
discoveryAddress: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
drainDuration: 45s
envoyAccessLogService: {}
envoyMetricsService: {}
parentShutdownDuration: 60s
proxyAdminPort: 15000
proxyMetadata:
  DNS_AGENT: ""
serviceCluster: reviews.default
statNameLength: 189
statusPort: 15020
terminationDrainDuration: 5s
tracing:
  zipkin:
    address: caadc76wvdp7edddddddccclii.apm-agt.ap-mumbai-1.oci.oraclecloud.com:443

2022-03-30T05:59:33.148721Z     info    Proxy role: &model.Proxy{RWMutex:sync.RWMutex{w:sync.Mutex{state:0, sema:0x0}, writerSem:0x0, readerSem:0x0, readerCount:0, readerWait:0}, Type:"sidecar", IPAddresses:[]string{"10.4.1.6"}, ID:"reviews-v1-5d6559df86-qbg6b.default", Locality:(*envoy_config_core_v3.Locality)(nil), DNSDomain:"default.svc.cluster.local", ConfigNamespace:"", Metadata:(*model.NodeMetadata)(nil), SidecarScope:(*model.SidecarScope)(nil), PrevSidecarScope:(*model.SidecarScope)(nil), MergedGateway:(*model.MergedGateway)(nil), ServiceInstances:[]*model.ServiceInstance(nil), IstioVersion:(*model.IstioVersion)(nil), VerifiedIdentity:(*spiffe.Identity)(nil), ipv6Support:false, ipv4Support:false, GlobalUnicastIP:"", XdsResourceGenerator:model.XdsResourceGenerator(nil), WatchedResources:map[string]*model.WatchedResource(nil)}
2022-03-30T05:59:33.148732Z     info    JWT policy is third-party-jwt
2022-03-30T05:59:33.148777Z     info    PilotSAN []string{"istiod.istio-system.svc"}
2022-03-30T05:59:33.148827Z     info    sa.serverOptions.CAEndpoint == istiod.istio-system.svc:15012 Citadel
2022-03-30T05:59:33.148916Z     info    Using CA istiod.istio-system.svc:15012 cert with certs: var/run/secrets/istio/root-cert.pem
2022-03-30T05:59:33.149082Z     info    citadelclient   Citadel client using custom root: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

2022-03-30T05:59:33.219251Z     info    sds     SDS gRPC server for workload UDS starts, listening on "./etc/istio/proxy/SDS"

2022-03-30T05:59:33.219548Z     info    xdsproxy        Initializing with upstream address istiod.istio-system.svc:15012 and cluster Kubernetes
2022-03-30T05:59:33.219346Z     info    sds     Start SDS grpc server
2022-03-30T05:59:33.220303Z     info    xdsproxy        adding watcher for certificate var/run/secrets/istio/root-cert.pem
2022-03-30T05:59:33.220894Z     info    Starting proxy agent
2022-03-30T05:59:33.222017Z     info    Opening status port 15020

2022-03-30T05:59:33.222278Z     info    Received new config, creating new Envoy epoch 0
2022-03-30T05:59:33.222328Z     info    Epoch 0 starting
2022-03-30T05:59:33.239683Z     info    Envoy command: [-c etc/istio/proxy/envoy-rev0.json --restart-epoch 0 --drain-time-s 45 --parent-shutdown-time-s 60 --service-cluster reviews.default --service-node sidecar~10.4.1.6~reviews-v1-5d6559df86-qbg6b.default~default.svc.cluster.local --local-address-ip-version v4 --bootstrap-version 3 --log-format-prefix-with-location 0 --log-format %Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ     %l      envoy %n        %v -l warning --component-log-level misc:error --config-yaml {
    "tracing": {
        "http": {
            "name": "envoy.tracers.zipkin",
            "typed_config": {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.trace.v3.ZipkinConfig",
                "collector_cluster": "aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com",
                "collector_endpoint": "/20200101/observations/public-span?dataFormat=zipkin&dataFormatVersion=2&dataKey=MAYH36IJELZRXTEETKL7QEA7NPA5UNEI",
                "collectorEndpointVersion": "HTTP_JSON",
                "trace_id_128bit": true,
                "shared_span_context": false
            }
        }
    },
    "static_resources": {
        "clusters": [{
            "name": "aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com:443",
            "connect_timeout": "5s",
            "type": "STRICT_DNS",
            "lb_policy": "ROUND_ROBIN",
            "load_assignment": {
                "cluster_name": "aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com",
                "endpoints": [{
                    "lb_endpoints": [{
                        "endpoint": {
                            "address": {
                                "socket_address": {
                                    "address": "aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com",
                                    "port_value": 443
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }]
            },
            "transport_socket": {
                "name": "envoy.transport_sockets.tls",
                "typed_config": {
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext",
                    "sni": "aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com"
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
 --concurrency 2]
2022-03-30T05:59:33.315619Z     warning envoy runtime   Unable to use runtime singleton for feature envoy.http.headermap.lazy_map_min_size
2022-03-30T05:59:33.315693Z     warning envoy runtime   Unable to use runtime singleton for feature envoy.http.headermap.lazy_map_min_size
2022-03-30T05:59:33.316469Z     warning envoy runtime   Unable to use runtime singleton for feature envoy.http.headermap.lazy_map_min_size
2022-03-30T05:59:33.316542Z     warning envoy runtime   Unable to use runtime singleton for feature envoy.http.headermap.lazy_map_min_size
2022-03-30T05:59:33.390651Z     info    xdsproxy        Envoy ADS stream established
2022-03-30T05:59:33.391110Z     info    xdsproxy        connecting to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2022-03-30T05:59:33.396461Z     warning envoy main      there is no configured limit to the number of allowed active connections. Set a limit via the runtime key overload.global_downstream_max_connections
2022-03-30T05:59:33.478768Z     info    sds     resource:ROOTCA new connection
2022-03-30T05:59:33.479543Z     info    sds     Skipping waiting for gateway secret
2022-03-30T05:59:33.479419Z     info    sds     resource:default new connection
2022-03-30T05:59:33.479917Z     info    sds     Skipping waiting for gateway secret
2022-03-30T05:59:33.682346Z     info    cache   Root cert has changed, start rotating root cert for SDS clients
2022-03-30T05:59:33.682714Z     info    cache   GenerateSecret default
2022-03-30T05:59:33.683386Z     info    sds     resource:default pushed key/cert pair to proxy
2022-03-30T05:59:34.079948Z     info    cache   Loaded root cert from certificate ROOTCA
2022-03-30T05:59:34.080300Z     info    sds     resource:ROOTCA pushed root cert to proxy
2022-03-30T05:59:34.154971Z     warning envoy config    gRPC config for type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.listener.v3.Listener rejected: Error adding/updating listener(s) 10.8.14.87_14250: envoy.tracers.zipkin: unknown cluster 'aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com'
0.0.0.0_20001: envoy.tracers.zipkin: unknown cluster 'aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com'
10.8.1.76_3000: envoy.tracers.zipkin: unknown cluster 'aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com'
0.0.0.0_9411: envoy.tracers.zipkin: unknown cluster 'aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com'
10.8.1.191_15021: envoy.tracers.zipkin: unknown cluster 'aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com'
0.0.0.0_9080: envoy.tracers.zipkin: unknown cluster 'aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com'
10.8.5.43_443: envoy.tracers.zipkin: unknown cluster 'aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com'
0.0.0.0_15010: envoy.tracers.zipkin: unknown cluster 'aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com'
0.0.0.0_15014: envoy.tracers.zipkin: unknown cluster 'aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com'
10.8.14.87_14268: envoy.tracers.zipkin: unknown cluster 'aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com'
0.0.0.0_80: envoy.tracers.zipkin: unknown cluster 'aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com'
0.0.0.0_9090: envoy.tracers.zipkin: unknown cluster 'aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com'
virtualInbound: envoy.tracers.zipkin: unknown cluster 'aaaabbbb.apm-agt.us-ashburn-1.oci.oraclecloud.com'

2022-03-30T05:59:35.844720Z     warn    Envoy proxy is NOT ready: config not received from Pilot (is Pilot running?): cds updates: 1 successful, 0 rejected; lds updates: 0 successful, 1 reje
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2-3 days of debugging was able to resolve distributed tracing issue with **istio**, **Zipkin** and **OCI APM**.

**Note** : With root user it was not working, so I created one compartment in OCI created IAM policy, group and give full access of compartment to the group.

Added root user to group and weirdly it started working while with direct root user and default policy it was not working.

Ref doc for policy : https://docs-uat.us.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/application-performance-monitoring/apmgn/perform-oracle-cloud-infrastructure-prerequisite-tasks.html

Working **configmap** sidecar

`connect_timeout` key is required otherwise sidecar is failing and due to that PODs won't come in **Ready** state. Port **443** mentioned in the official documentation is not required.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: istio-custom-bootstrap-config
data:
  custom_bootstrap.json: |
    {
        "tracing": {
            "http": {
                "name": "envoy.tracers.zipkin",
                "typed_config": {
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.trace.v3.ZipkinConfig",
                    "collector_cluster": "aacytncaaaaaaaal2a.apm-agt.ap-mumbai-1.oci.oraclecloud.com", 
                    "collector_endpoint": "/20200101/observations/public-span?dataFormat=zipkin&dataFormatVersion=2&dataKey=M7SOSHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXUZEHOGRSA",
                    "collector_endpoint_version": "HTTP_JSON",
                    "trace_id_128bit": true,
                    "shared_span_context": false
                }
            }
        },
        "static_resources": {
            "clusters": [{
                "name": "aacytncaaaaaaaal2a.apm-agt.ap-mumbai-1.oci.oraclecloud.com",
                "type": "STRICT_DNS",
                "connect_timeout": "5s",
                "lb_policy": "ROUND_ROBIN",
                "load_assignment": {
                    "cluster_name": "aacytncaaaaaaaal2a.apm-agt.ap-mumbai-1.oci.oraclecloud.com", 
                    "endpoints": [{
                        "lb_endpoints": [{
                            "endpoint": {
                                "address": {
                                    "socket_address": {
                                        "address": "aacytncaaaaaaaal2a.apm-agt.ap-mumbai-1.oci.oraclecloud.com", 
                                        "port_value": 443
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }]
                },
                "transport_socket": {
                    "name": "envoy.transport_sockets.tls",
                    "typed_config": {
                        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext",
                        "sni": "aacytncaaaaaaaal2a.apm-agt.ap-mumbai-1.oci.oraclecloud.com" 
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```

**Istio config**

`sampling: 100` will push mostly all traces to **Zipkin** and **OCI APM domain**. Also i enabled `enableTracing: true`

Read more at : https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/mesh-and-proxy-config/

```
data:
  mesh: |-
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
    enableTracing: true
    defaultConfig:
      discoveryAddress: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
      proxyMetadata: {}
      tracing:
        sampling: 100
        zipkin:
          address: aacytncaaaaaaaal2a.apm-agt.ap-mumbai-1.oci.oraclecloud.com:443
    enablePrometheusMerge: true
    rootNamespace: istio-system
    outboundTrafficPolicy:
      mode: ALLOW_ANY
    trustDomain: cluster.local
  meshNetworks: 'networks: {}'
```

**OCI console**

[image]